# Smooth toggle effect in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to let the transition when you click the button smoother, but it's not working, I tried to add `$slideToggle`, but I think I did it wrong.

```html
<button class="btn btn-warning" id="btn-mob">
<div id="rec-div" style="display: none;">
  test
</div>

<script>
  $("#btn-mob").click(function() {
    $("#rec-div").toggle();
    $("#rec-div").slideToggle(1500);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I tried your code and it works. Just one thing, you need to remove the additional `toggle()`, before the `slideToggle()`. Is this the intended animation?

```js
 $( "#btn-mob" ).click(function() {
  $("#rec-div").slideToggle(1500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-warning" id="btn-mob">
<div id="rec-div" style="display: none;">test</div>
```

Comment: It's working fine now!!! It was not working with JQuery.min, so I had to change it to uncompressed version. Thank you for helping me :)